# Connect IQ Garmin Simulator test getting location by enableLocationEvents function

Tags: garmin, connectiq, monkeyc

I need find position of watch.
I have an method:

```
function initializeListener() as Void {
    System.println("start");
    Position.enableLocationEvents(Position.LOCATION_ONE_SHOT, method(:onPosition));
}

function onPosition( info as Position.Info ) as Void {
    System.println("I found you!");
    System.println( "Position " + info );
}
```

I tryeing to set position by option:

> settings->set position

and I change GPS Quality by

> settings->set GPS Quality

to "Good".

But still method onPosition is not callable. Enybody know how I can simulate getting position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the simulator is not configured to send activity data. To do this, go to the menu item "Simulation -> Activity Data" and press the play button. This will result in the simulator updating the various sensors with simulated data every 1 second. You can also playback a FIT file from that menu dialog.